# How to reinitialise jScrollPane without losing features added in the first initialisation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I'm having trouble with jScrollPane's `reinitialise()` method. Whenever I call it, stuff that I implemented in the first initialisation stops working...

In my current code, I'm doing something like this:

```
$('.scrollable').each(function(){

    var e = $(this),
        parent = e.parent();

    e.jScrollPane({
        // parameters
    });

    var api = e.data('jsp'),
        arrowup = e.find('.jspArrowUp'),
        arrowdw = e.find('.jspArrowDown');

    if ( api.getIsScrollableV() ) {
        e.addClass('scrolled-top');
        parent.addClass('scroll-parent');
    }

    e.scroll(function(){
        var scrbef = api.getContentPositionY(),
            scrmax = api.getContentHeight() - this.clientHeight,
            scraft = scrmax - scrbef,
            dlayup = (scrbef - 220)/100,
            dlaydw = (scraft - 220)/100,
            opacup = dlayup > 1 ? 1 : dlayup < 0 ? 0 : dlayup,
            opacdw = dlaydw > 1 ? 1 : dlaydw < 0 ? 0 : dlaydw;

        if ( scrbef === 0 ) {
            e.addClass('scrolled-top').removeClass('scrolled-bot');
        } else if ( scraft === 0 ) {
            e.addClass('scrolled-bot').removeClass('scrolled-top');
        } else {
            e.removeClass('scrolled-top scrolled-bot');
        }

        arrowup.css('opacity', opacup);
        arrowdw.css('opacity', opacdw);
    });
```

So far, so good. What that does is:

- initialise jScrollPane on the `.scrollable` elements
- depending on the content position, add or remove `scrolled-top` or `scrolled-bot` classes.
- **controls the opacity of the arrows depending on the content's position** (there's a lot of padding at the top and bottom, so I only want the arrows to appear when the actual content has reached the border of the screen).

Right after that bit, I have this:

```
    var throttleTimeout;

    $(window).resize(function(){
        if ( !throttleTimeout ) {
            throttleTimeout = setTimeout( function(){
                    api.reinitialise();

                    throttleTimeout = null;
                }, 500
            );
        }
    });

    $('.deployer').click(function(e){
        api.reinitialise();
    });
});
```

Now, that is pretty straightforward; the code to reinitialise when the window is resized comes straight from the documentation.

However, as soon as either `reinitialise()` is called, so after resizing the window or clicking on the `.deployer` element, **the previous code which controlled the arrows' opacity stops working** – although, weirdly enough, the `scrolled-top` and `scrolled-bot` classes still get added or removed properly.

Does anyone know what might be causing this behaviour and how to fix it?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what was happening.

Whenever you reinitialise, basically everything gets resetted, so the elements that were previously stored in `arrowup` and `arrowdw` don't exist anymore. Adding

```
var arrowup = e.find('.jspArrowUp'),
    arrowdw = e.find('.jspArrowDown');
```

again after each `reinitialise()` made the trick.